# TLS certificate for SNIproxy, or a reverse proxy with virtual host with a TLS certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

I currently use SNIProxy (it's the simplest I've seen so far to set up virtual hosts). However, I can only set SSL certificates separately per virtual host with each service's configuration (each one is on a separate port), which can quickly become a problem, and not for the server as a whole, so I only need a certificate for the reverse proxy. So, is there a way to do it? Alternatively, is there a reverse proxy that supports virtual hosts (preferably with wildcards, so that `test.*` will go to `test.com`, `test.net`, `test.org`, etc.) and setting a TLS certificate for inly that proxy (I still can't figure out how to do it in NGINX or Caddy; NGINX only supports hosts per folder, and Caddy doesn't support custom certificates, though I can be wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is putting the virtual hosts in SNIProxy on localhost http, and putting NGINX as a HTTPS frontend to it, so that when it recieves a request, it shuttles it to localhost along with the host header.

For posterity, here is my configs:

For SNIProxy:

```
user nobody
pidfile /run/sniproxy/sniproxy.pid

error_log {
    syslog deamon
    priority notice
}

listen 127.0.0.1:8000 {
    proto http
}

table {
    whoogle.* 127.0.0.1:2000
    
    adguard.* 127.0.0.1:2001

    bitwarden.* 127.0.0.1:2002
    
    thea.* 127.0.0.1:2003

    files.* 127.0.0.1:2004

    photopea.* 127.0.0.1:2005

    desmos.* 127.0.0.1:2006

    youtube.* 127.0.0.1:2007

}
```

and nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        /dev/null;

daemon off;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    proxy_temp_path ./tmp;
    access_log /dev/null;
    ssl_certificate ./cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key ./key.pem;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    client_body_temp_path ./tmp;

    server {
            listen       127.0.0.1:443 ssl;
    
            server_name  *.test;
    
            location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            }
        }
    
        server {
            listen       192.168.1.67:443 ssl;
            
            server_name  *.tt;
    
            location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            }
        }

        server {
                    listen       127.0.0.1:80;
                    
                    server_name  *.test;

                    return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
                }
            
                server {
                    listen       192.168.1.67:80;
                    
                    server_name  *.tt;

                    return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
                }
}
```